# importing model as function, sequelize fixtures not import data from json file: Unhandled rejection Error return?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

In my node js project I am using express and sequelize. I would like to create some fixtures in order to populate my data tables.

Using [Sequelize-fixtures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-fixtures-fixed) npm, this is my `fixtures.js` file:

```
'use strict';

const sequelize_fixtures = require('sequelize-fixtures');

// define all the model
const models = {
            Mission: require(__dirname+'/../models/mission.js')
        };

var fixtures =[
    {
        "model": "Mission",
        "data": {
            "description": "mission test 1",
            "state": "pending",
            "slug" : "mission-test-1"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "Mission",
        "data": {
            "description": "mission test 2",
            "state": "finished",
            "slug" : "mission-test-2"
        }
    }
];
// export and load fixtures
module.exports = {
    loadFixtures: () => {
        // can use glob syntax to select multiple files
        sequelize_fixtures.loadFixtures(fixtures, models).then(function(){
            console.log("Fixtures have been loaded, check your database tables ;) !!!");
        });
    }
};
```

In the root of my project I call this module like this in `server.js` :

```
// ...
// Importing sequelize
let database = require(__dirname + '/database/database');
let fixturesLoader = require(__dirname+'/database/fixtures/fixtures.js');
```

But I have this error now in my console when I restart the node server:

> Unhandled rejection Error: models.Mission appears to be a function.
>   Perhaps you are importing model factory function? You should then use
>   sequelize.import to create your model, see
>   https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js#L17

Of course I check the link, and this is how I use sequelize and the configuration in a file named database.js:

```
'use strict';

const fs        = require('fs');
const path      = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config    = require(__dirname+'/database.json');
const db        = {};

let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.dbname, config.db.user, config.db.password, {
    host: config.db.host,
    port: config.db.port,
    define: {
        // And deletedAt to be called destroyTime (remember to enable paranoid for this to work)
        deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
        paranoid: true,
        // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
        underscored: true,
        // disable the modification of table names; By default, sequelize will automatically
        // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
        freezeTableName: true,
        charset: 'utf8',
        collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
        timestamps: true,
        language: 'fr'
    }
});

fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/models').filter(function (file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0);
}).forEach(function (file) {
    let model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname + '/models', file));
    db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
    if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I understand that I am importing my model as function, but following the doc, I don't understand how to import them without this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this issue by commenting this two lines in sequelize-fixtures/lib/loader.js:

```js
if (!Model) {
        throw new Error('Model not found: ' + fixture.model);
    // } else if (typeof Model === 'function') {
    //     throw new Error('models.' + fixture.model + ' appears to be a function. Perhaps you are importing model factory function? You should then use sequelize.import to create your model, see https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js#L17');
    } else if (!Model.findOne) {
        throw new Error('models.' + fixture.model + ' is not a sequelize model.');
    }
```

Comment: and it works like a charm for me ! Thank you for your answer, you save my day !